# Passing Parameters to Pages in a Secure Manner

Tags: .net, security

Hi I was wondering in .NET 2.0 what is the best way to transfer parameters between pages?  I cannot allow the user to modify these parameters, so I was thinking of using Session variables. Is this a safe method?  Is there a way for the user to modify it?

Answer (score 2):

Users cannot modify variables you store in Session[].

But you should still be aware of other session attacks like Session Fixation, and Session Hijacking.  ASP.Net abstracts aware a lot of this security and handles it for you, but it's still good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You could also store it in the ViewState and set enableViewStateMAC to true.  ViewState validation would fail if anyone tampered with the viewstate data.

Answer (score 0):

For it to be secure 100% it should be kept on the server.
Session is a good choice (also DB, but it require more resources-> less performance).
Although I say 100%, it depends on how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way a user can modify the Session state without tricking your application to modify it for them.  So for keeping info about the user secure between responses its a decent starting point.

[Don't think the session state is completely safe however...](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/2.0_Session_State_(in)security_(and_the_dangers_of_State_Server))